# How to access object properties from within object method?

Tags: c++

I have this class named `Enemy` from which `Ninja` inherits its properties. In `Ninja`'s attack function, I'm trying to call `Ninja`'s `getAttackPower` function, but how do I get it. I tried calling `this.getAttackPower` but it didn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

class Enemy {
    int attackPower;
    public:
        virtual void attack() { cout << "I am attacking you!"; }
    protected:
        int getAttackPower() {
            return attackPower;
        }
        void setAttackPower( int a ) {
            attackPower = a;
        }
};

class Ninja : public Enemy {
    void attack() {
        cout << "(minus " << getAttackPower() << " points).";
        // .................. right here ......
    }
};

int main() {
    Ninja ninjaObj;

    ninjaObj.setAttackPower(23);

    ninjaObj.getAttackPower();

}
```

Here are the errors I'm getting:

```
void Enemy::setAttackPower(int) is protected
error: within this context
error: 'int Enemy::getAttackPower()' is protected
error: within this context
```

Comment: Dude, `this` is a pointer. How can you call `this.whatever`?

Comment: I'm new to c++. I'm coming from JS.

Comment: @David OK, fair enough. Here's some introductory material which you need to read first: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Comment: @David you want `this->whatever`. `this` is a pointer. Pointers are just 32-bit or 64-bit numbers representing memory locations (the location where you will find the actual object), so if you want to access the object it points to you either need to use `->` instead of a dot or `(*this)` to grab the object. (`(*this).whatever` is the same as `this->whatever`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in `main` not `attack`. You set your access modifier for `Enemy::setAttackPower(int)` and `Enemy::getAttackPower()` to `protected`. That means these methods are treated as `private` unless if you're inside a class that **extends Enemy**.

That means when you are in `main` it can't access `ninjaObj.setAttackPower(23)` because `main` is **outside the scope of any object**.

If you call `ninjaObj.attack()`, however, it will also fail because you did not set an access modifier for `Ninja::attack()`, so it **defaults to private**.

To fix: add `public:` in front of `Ninja::attack()`, and do not call `Enemy::setAttackPower(int)` or `Enemy::getAttackPower()` in `main`.

Comment: Thanks. But how will I be able to set and get the attack power then?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it working. See here -- http://collabedit.com/mvjad Thanks for the help!